# File changes do not show up in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm experimenting with VSCode(specifically version `1.17.1`),
 and I noticed if I change the content of some files programatically, the updated content doesn't appear immediately and I need to close and reopen the file!

Is this a common issue with VSCode, and how to solve it if there is any solution that doesn't involve a **refresh command** or a key binding like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue using MAC OS and VSC version 1.18. It's definitely something they need to address.